# OpenSSH on a Windows box using domain authentication: can't logon

Tags: ssh, openssh

On my windows 2008 box I just did what the steps said:

- mkgroup -d >> ..\etc\group
- mkpasswd -d -u username >> ..\etc\passwd

In my passwd file, I see my user like it's been pulled in from the domain, but I can't ssh into the box from my other windows machine. I get the following:

```
C:\oc\chef>ssh 'user@domain.com'@machine169
user@domain.com@machine169169's password: [][][][]
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Is there a step I'm missing?

Comment: Tried:

1) "ssh user:domain@server" and 2)
"ssh -l user@domain server"

Neither worked for me. Permission denied also.

Answer (score 1):

## Update the OpenSSH to a newer version

Internet still point you to http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/. But that project is not being maintained. Use http://www.mls-software.com/opensshd.html instead.

By the time of writing, the *sshwindows* port is at version 3.8, but the *opensshd* port from *mls-software* is at version 7.3.

## Check the contents of the `passwd` file for the domain name as OpenSSH expects it

Find the line beginning with your user name. The lines are records delimited by colons `:`.

See what is the content of the fifth field. It will tell you exactly what is the domain name considered by SSH.

## Use an alternative connection syntax

So, to connect to the `server`, given that the domain name in the `passwd` file for the user `user` is  `DOMAIN`, you can connect with any of this:

```
ssh user:DOMAIN@server
ssh -l user:DOMAIN server
```

> Iportant: OpenSSH is case sensitive. So write the username and domain name exactly as they appear in the `passwd` file.